# Cannot Insert NULL into NTEXT field in SQL CE?

Tags: insert, null, sql-server-ce, ntext

A simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE People (
      personID     int          not null
    , name         nvarchar(50)  not null
    , addrLine1    nvarchar(50) null
    , addrLine2    nvarchar(50) null
    , suburb       nvarchar(30) not null
    , xmlRawInput  ntext        not null
    , xmlRawOutput ntext        null
) 
GO


INSERT People (
      personID          
    , name              
    , addrLine1         
    , addrLine2         
    , suburb            
    , xmlRawInput       
    , xmlRawOutput
)
SELECT
      101             AS personID           
    , 'george benson'   AS name
    , '123 help st'   AS addrLine1
    , NULL            AS addrLine2          
    , 'los angeles'   AS suburb
    , '<example>record<example>' AS xmlRawInput     
    , 'I LOVE MICROSOFT' AS xmlRawOutput
GO
```

This works fine; Notice Null can easily be inserted into addrLine2 column; But if i change 
'I Love Microsoft' to NULL on the ntext column, i get following error:
The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = int, Type to convert to (if known) = ntext ]

Insert fails for below; any ideas? I am using CE version 3.5.8080.0.

```
INSERT People (
      personID          
    , name              
    , addrLine1         
    , addrLine2         
    , suburb            
    , xmlRawInput       
    , xmlRawOutput
)
SELECT
      101             AS personID           
    , 'george benson'   AS name
    , '123 help st'   AS addrLine1
    , NULL            AS addrLine2          
    , 'los angeles'   AS suburb
    , '<example>record<example>' AS xmlRawInput     
    , NULL AS xmlRawOutput
GO
```

Comment: Looks like a bug - can you try on a previous version and see if it manifests itself there?

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas to try:

Use a `values` clause instead of `select` clause in your `insert`, ie:

```
INSERT People (
      personID          
    , name              
    , addrLine1         
    , addrLine2         
    , suburb            
    , xmlRawInput       
    , xmlRawOutput
)
VALUES (
      101
    , 'george benson'
    , '123 help st'
    , NULL     
    , 'los angeles'
    , '<example>record<example>'
    , NULL 
)
```

If, for some reason, you must use the `select` clause (why?), try casting the `NULL` to `ntext` explicitly.  ie, `select convert(ntext, NULL)`.

If the `values` clause works, then the cause is probably the SqlCE engine being dumb and using the wrong default datatype for the `null` in the `select` statement.  The `convert` may or may not work, depending on what datatype `null` takes on first, since technically you can't cast anything to `ntext` ... but it's worth trying.

Comment: Thank you. This is a problem with the uniqueidentifier type as well.